# iOS: How do I put an image on top of the tableView like iBook

Tags: ios, tableview, ibooks

If you scroll all the way up on the iBook, you can see an apple mark (above search and two buttons). How can you put such image on top of the TableView?

My first guess is that apple just used an image as its background and somehow aligned it right. Am I on right track?

Answer (score 0):

It's a `UIImageView`, either set as a `tableHeaderView` (check the docs) with the table given negative-top `contentInset`, or just added as a subview of the table view itself. The latter's probably simpler—just set the image view's position to something with a negative Y value.

Comment: Hi Noah, thank you for your reply. 
I looked into the tableHeaderView before and I don't think that little image is an headerview. HeaderView often contains a search bar or a cell item and it won't look the same as one in the iBook. User will be able to scroll to that item. 

I should try an imageView positioned with negative Y value